# Is the Google Nest Doorbell Battery (2021) accessible through the SDM API?

Tags: nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

I have followed this https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/get-started

Getting error when I try to authorize my account:

> No access to partner
>
> Information could not be retrieved. Please contact Nest Api to verify
> that your account has been properly set up. You may need to add the
> developer email address as a home member in the Google Home app
> settings.

I'm starting to suspect that the new Nest Doorbell is not supported by the new SDM API for Nest.
Anyone had any success in accessing the doorbell through the API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/support points to "nest-device-access". And I really just want to know if the API supports the new models before I spend more time trying to fix something thats not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spoke with Google Support - the new devices (doorbell (battery) and Cams) are not supported at this moment. No further information if it will be supported in the future.

Comment: Its supported now!

Comment: All the new camera/doorbell devices are supported now, though with fairly limited functionality...

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is seeing this later those devices are supported now:

[supported cameras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgptK.png)

I suspect but am not sure that the error shown in the initial question would not be related to whether or not a device is supported but something with the way the account is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your gmail which is being used on the device access console should be added to the google home. Make sure you can access google home with that gmail is added to the family

Comment: Using the same account everywhere

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/pcm?hl=en#no_access_to_partner

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. The new Doorbell isn't supported. Also the new Cam is not supported, if you ask me.